# A double outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I have a table People, a table Permission and a table Action. Permission is there to provide a many-to-many relationship between People and Action.

My goal is simple : I want to look for one person in People, I want to see the permission listed in Permission, AND every action available, wether the person has the permission or not.

Note that a member of People is not necessary represented in Permission. So, "John" is only allowed to do something if he's got the permission written in the database.

Ideally, the result would look something like :

```
+-------------------------------------------+
+ People.name | Action.name        |Allowed |
+-------------------------------------------+
| John Doe    | Launching missiles | N      |
| John Doe    | Deleting code      | Y      |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Before I get to there, I'm simply tring to build a simple query with every data. 
Getting the list of permission of someone, even if he is not present in the permission table is easy :

```
SELECT * FROM people pp LEFT OUTER JOIN permission pr ON pp.id = pr.people_id 
WHERE pp.name = 'John';
```

Getting the list of permission and actions is easy :

```
SELECT * FROM permission pr LEFT OUTER JOIN action a ON pr.action_id = a.id
```

However, I can't seem to perform a double outer join that would get me everything I want :

```
SELECT * FROM people pp LEFT OUTER JOIN permission pr ON pp.id = pr.permission_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN people WHERE pp.name = 'John'
```

Shows John, the fact that he's got no permission... but no actions whatsoever.

In other words, results look something like :

```
+-----------------------------------------+
+ Name    | People_id | Action_id |Action |
+-----------------------------------------+
| John    |           |           |       |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

When I wanted :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
+ Name    | People_id | Action_id |Action                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| John    |           |           | Launching missiles      |
| John    |           |           | Deleting codes          |
| John    |           |           | (every other actions)   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, is what I want possible ? If so, how can I achieve it ? (I'm using PostgreSQL).

**edit**: Here is a sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d502

Comment: I'm somewhat confused: "I have a table People, a table Permission and a table Action. Interdiction is there to provide a many-to-many relationship between People and Publication." - shouldn't this be "Permission" instead of "Publication" ?

Comment: Can you please post a schema and sample data? Your query doesn't join to Action, so I don't see how it returns the column headers you list...a SQLFiddle would be great.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : Permission and not interdiction, Action and not Publication. I've fixed it, sorry ! And I added a fiddle as Neville suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT 
    P.name as "people.name", 
    IFNULL(pm.id_people,''), 
    IFNULL(pm.id_action,''), 
    A.name as "action.name"
FROM Action A
CROSS JOIN People P
LEFT JOIN permission pm 
    ON pm.id_action = a.id
    AND pm.id_people = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pp.name, pr.id_people, pr.id_action, a.name as action_name
 FROM people pp
 CROSS JOIN action a
 LEFT JOIN permission pr
   ON pr.id_people = pp.id
  AND pr.id_action = a.id
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a7b1/4

To filter by person name add to query:

```
WHERE pp.name = 'John'
```

Comment: Cross join ! That's what I was missing ! Thank you !